# Suppress keyboard from popping up

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to stop keyboard from popping up in my android app. I wish to add this code

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) 
        getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 
        0);
    }
}
```

but I am not sure where to insert in my `MainActivity.java` file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having the keyboard pop-up add this to your `onCreate()` method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: that looks good. I tried another approach which worked.  android:focusableInTouchMode="true" in xml file. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the keyboard to show when your activity gets focus then you can add attributes in the manifest:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" . . . >
```

This manipulates how the main window of the activity interacts with the window containing the on-screen soft keyboard. The setting for this attribute affects the state of the soft keyboard — whether it is hidden or visible — when the activity becomes the focus of user attention.
You can use one of the following attribute depending on your requirement :

1. "**stateHidden**"   The soft keyboard is hidden when the user chooses the activity — that is, when the user affirmatively navigates forward to the activity, rather than backs into it because of leaving another activity.
2. "**stateAlwaysHidden**" The soft keyboard is always hidden when the activity's main window has input focus.

If you want to do it programatically then you can use your method in onCreate

Comment: that looks good. I tried another approach which worked.  android:focusableInTouchMode="true" in xml file. thanks